# How to re-publish every entry?

Tags: channel-entries, search

Long story short, I forgot to set all my Playa fields to searchable and through incompatible versions of SuperSearch and Playa my exp_channel_data table was not populated correctly.

The only solution is to re-publish every entry again (which entails literally going to the edit page and clicking publish for that entry).

Does anybody know a quick and dirty way to do this before I have to bust out a script?

Thanks!